# Further clarification of an IE7 Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I believe I came across a memory leak in IE7. One of our pages was crashing when the user navigated away from it. From doing some debugging, I came across the following piece of code which seems to be culprit, considering the page works fine when I comment it out.

```
$$('.someClass').each(function(item, index) {
    $(item).addEvent('click', function(e) {
        if (e) e.preventDefault();
        // ...

        // MEMORY LEAK??
        var userId = $(item).getElement('a').id.substr(10);

        // ...
    });
});
```

This is a case where you need to break the cycle between the DOM element and `userId` variable, correct? I'm still struggling with the concept a little bit.

Comment: The code snippet wouldn't have any effect on what happens when the page is navigated away from. I don't think that's your culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying that (may I assume it's mootools?), and can confirm the leak.

It doesn't matter what you do inside the each(),  the each() creates the leak. On Every page-load I get 2 leaks, 1 for the HTML-element and 1 for a DIV-element.

The DIV is not a part of the DOM(tested it with no DIV's inside the document), it's been created by mootools  for testing-purposes. The leaks also occur when I use only this:

```
$$('.someClass').each(function(){});
```

So what may I suggest: **don't use mootools ^^**

---

P.S: Tested with mootools-core-1.4.4-full-compat.js , IE6 and [sIEve](http://home.orange.nl/jsrosman/)

Answer (score 0):

There's no memory leak there.  `userId` is just a string variable that has no connection to anything.  As soon as it goes out of scope, the browser will garbage collect it.

Comment: You know, it went away when I commented that code but then it showed up again. I'll investigate further and then update my question if I can figure it out. Thanks.